# How do you tell the data source table in SSRS web portal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to find out what table in SQL database my report used in the SSRS web portal.

The Data sources section has the following information:

```
A custom data source
Connection string: Data Source=SQLSERVER101;Initial Catalog=DB101
```

But `DB101` is a database rather than a table. Is there a way for me check which table the data is taken from?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This info is only held in the dataset query, so you will have to read the report design to view it.

Answer (score 0):

The source data could be found in the report.

Click on Edit in Report Builder under Properties:
[image]

Then in the report, the tables being used are under the "Datasets" section.

To alter column data format:

Right-click a dataset in the Report Data pane and then click Dataset Properties.

See [Add a Filter to a Dataset (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/add-a-filter-to-a-dataset-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)